# Possible to find WPDB results based on number range?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Is it possible to retrieve rows from a WPDB table where the number is within a range? For example, if I have a db row saved as

```
ID | HEADER_IMG  | RANGE
1  | smiling.jpg | 12
2  | family.jpg  | 10-20
3  | picnic.jpg  | 18, 21
```

Is there a way to pull out the second entry by searching for a number within that range, like 15? Or do I have to run a `LIKE` query for the dash and then post-process those results using a custom function? If there's potentially hundreds of rows stored, which way would be most efficient to locate results based on range?

Maybe I'm not explaining correctly; I'll edit my question if needs be. I've hunted all over and the `BETWEEN` operator isn'y what I'm looking for as far as I can tell.

EDIT: If **normalization** would be key to making this type of functionality work, how do I go about structuring the table so I can save quickly, and then retrieve large spans of rows on page load? I don't understand how normalizing the table would make this possible, so any help in this regard would be fantastic.

I have a range of pages that all need to have the same settings applied. I'm saving the settings in ranges so I don't have to save identical settings for each page repeatedly.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should care about normalizing your structure

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid That's not helpful in the least. The database example I used is  obviously an example.

Comment: Because you are storing no.s as strings as csv or separated by dashes on which you need to perform search, That is why i mentioned normalize your structure so that you can easily query and there will no overhead on DB side

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have a range of pages that all need to have the same settings applied. I'm saving the settings in ranges so I don't have to save identical settings for each page repeatedly.

Comment: @ralphthewonderllama it's incredibly helpful. Normalise your ranges - for instance by separating range start and range end in separate columns

Comment: @Strawberry That's helpful. :) It's the end of day...I've never dealt with this sort of thing and I've been staring at code, and searching, for hours and not getting anywhere. Thank you for hitting me in the face with it. *facepalm* D'oh...